# Browser sources css file but does not apply it

Tags: python, css, django, nginx

I am trying to host a Django web application using nginx as a reverse proxy and waitress as the application server. I am running this on windows.

Static javascript assets load correctly on the page, but css does not. I have tried clearing my cache before refreshing the page, but that is not the problem as developer tools show the page correctly fetching the css file from the server. Additionally, I have tried navigating directly to "http://localhost:8888/static/css/styles.css" directly, and I can see the contents of the file.

Does anyone have any idea why the browser would correctly fetch the file but not display it on the page?

**nginx.conf**

```
server {

    # Running port
    listen 8888;

    # Settings to serve static files 
    location ^~ /static  {

        alias "C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\django-dev\\appname\\static\\";

    }

    # Proxy connections to the application servers
    # app_servers
    location / {

        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8081;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

    }
```

**Request I am making**: http://localhost:8888/static/css/styles.css

**html stylesheet reference**
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/styles.css">`

**EDIT:** For future reference, I solved this. nginx was sending over the css with incorrect headers, so I got a mime type error. Adding "include mime.types" to the HTTP block of my nginx.conf solved the problem.